# Add bookmark to existing pdf by mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using php and mpdf library,I want to add bookmark to uploaded existing pdf files to particular page. Please guide me, I try with following code but nothing happens.

```
    <?php
// Install mPDF
require_once '../MPDF/mpdf.php';

// Create a new mPDF object
$mpdf = new mPDF();

// Enable imports
$mpdf->SetImportUse();

// Open the PDF file that you want to add a bookmark to
$pagecount = $mpdf->setSourceFile('testpdf.pdf');

// Create a new bookmark
$mpdf->Bookmark('Bookmark Title', 0, 1);
// Save the PDF file
$mpdf->Output('new.pdf', 'F');
?>
```

Comment: According to the documentation, the "Bookmark" method can contain a maximum of 3 parameters, but you define 4 parameters, isn't that your problem?

Comment: Thanks for reply, even with 3 parameter same issue, main problem is I want to add bookmark in existing pdf files, not in new blank file